# Displaying white screen when opening React-Native from existing native android App

Tags: reactjs, react-native, screen, native

In Android, integrating react native to an existing app. Basically, my android app was originally developed in Java. From the java side, I click on the button to go to another screen that is using React Native.

Then, there is a problem, every time I click the button that opens the App.js (which contains stack navigation), it takes 2 or 3 seconds in a white screen (loading the bundle). so how to avoid this white screen?

**Updated Code**

```
const Navigation = StackNavigator({
home:{
    screen: HomeScreen,
}
})
class MyApp extends Component {
render() {
    return (
    <Navigation/>
    );
 }
}

export default MyApp;
AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => Navigation);
```

Comment: Can you post the way you are initializing your react provider and your react activity, also when are you initializing the react instance.

Comment: Please see I have added App.js Updated code in question